# Powershell to copy some specific files and some subfolders to destination

Tags: powershell, batch-processing, copy-item

I have a folder **source**. It has the following files:

```
image_00000.jpg
...
...
image_08000.jpg
```

And some subfolders which have **Negatives** appended at  the end:

My goal is to copy specific files say from, everything except **image_00000.jpg to image_00250.jpg** set. In addition I also need to copy some subfolders having which have **Negatives** appended at  the end.

I wrote the following script:

```
cls

$source = "All_flowers_images_negatives"
$destination = "Passion_Flower_Negative_Images_temp" 
<#
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse)
{
    if ($i.Name -match "image_(?!(000\d\d|001\d\d|002[0-4]\d|0025[0-1]))\d{5}\.jpg")
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)
    }
}
#>
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse)
{
    if ($i.Name -match "Negatives$")
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)
    }
}
```

Selective file copy works(thats why I have commented it out) but the second command copies only the folder structure not any files inside those subfolders. What changes should I make?

**EDIT1:** The code has been edited with the problem still persisting.
**EDIT2:** It works with `copy-item -recurse` and my objective has been achieved but still I am getting,

```
Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported.
At F:\_102flowers-500X500\copy_positives_Passion_Flower.ps1:18 char:18
+         Copy-Item <<<<  -Recurse -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Why?

Comment: try `copy-item -recurse ...`

Comment: I am sorry, I had written wrong code. See my edit in the code. Now answer the question with the same problem still persisting

Comment: @Kayasax : I tried -recurse. It worked.  My objective has been achieved but I am getting error too!(though it doesn't concern me now). See the edit

Comment: try to print `$i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)` to check the full path you get

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. Because of my complete unfamiliarity with Powershell, I couldn't write any proper code at all. I went to little details scrutiny in the Copy-Item and found that, since I had used the same command for copying files it worked but for subfolder it needed a slight change.

Here is the correct solution:

```
cls

$source = "All_flowers_images_negatives"
$destination = "Passion_Flower_Negative_Images_temp" 
<#
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse)
{
    if ($i.Name -match "image_(?!(000\d\d|001\d\d|002[0-4]\d|0025[0-1]))\d{5}\.jpg")
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)
    }
}
#>
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse)
{
    if ($i.Name -match "Negatives$")
    {
        Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
    }
}
```

The thing is, `Trim($i.Name)` is needed for trimming the name of the files from folder complete path-Makes sense but in case of copying the sub-directories, writing,

```
$i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)
```

does the job for replacement of path and no trimming is needed because there is no file involved